# Cordova screen orientation plugin, screen is flashing when changing orientation on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, screen-orientation

I'm developing an app using Cordova/Ionic, and using the [screen orientation plugin](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) for several different app screens.

On Android everything works just as fine, though while testing on iOS device (7.1), whenever I unlock the orientation to allow both landscape and portrait on a certain screen, and then going back to a screen that is fixed on portrait, it flashes quickly with a black screen for about 100ms during the 'orientation fix'.

I wonder if anyone encountered a similar situation before, that would be extremely helpful.

Much thanks!

Comment: don't assume there is only one orientation plugin, link the one you are using. And if you think it's a bug in the plugin, file an issue on the github page

Comment: You are right, my apologies... I have already submitted an issue and thought I have resolved it, but that was not completely solved. I have added the plugin used, and will file another issue upon this. Thanks!